# can i rename the table which generated by inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, the structure of them as follows:

table1:

```
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+
| id | rank_before_promotion | rank_after_promotion |
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+
| 01 |         GR01          |         GR02         |
| 02 |         GR03          |         GR04         |
| 03 |         GR03          |         GR05         |
| 04 |         GR06          |         GR07         |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

table2:

```
+------+------+
| rank | area | 
+------+------+
| GR01 | 1000 |    
| GR02 | 1200 |     
| GR03 | 1400 |     
| GR04 | 1600 | 
+-------------+
```

I want to calculate the difference between the area of rank_before_promotion and the area of rank_after_promotion with this sql:

```
     SELECT id, rank_before_promoton, rank_after_promotion, tmp1.area-tmp2.area 
     FROM (table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON rank_before_promotion = rank) AS tmp1,
          (table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON rank_after_promotion = rank) AS tmp2;
```

There are some error when i run this sql. Can i rename the table which generated by join? And is there a method to print the table generated by join?

The desired output will be:

```
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+--------+
| id | rank_before_promotion | rank_after_promotion | differ |
+----+-----------------------+----------------------+--------+
| 01 |         GR01          |         GR02         |   200  |
| 02 |         GR03          |         GR04         |   200  |
| 03 |         GR03          |         GR05         |   400  |
| 04 |         GR06          |         GR07         |   200  |
+---------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: several issues with your query indeed, for example deduction of strings `tmp1.area-tmp2.area`, table name parenthesized with joins...

Comment: Adding desired output would help us understand what the query should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you're attempting to achieve subtracting a string from another, but here's a version of your query that executes:

```
 SELECT id, rank_before_promotion, rank_after_promotion, b.area-c.area 
 FROM table1 a
 INNER JOIN table2 b
    ON a.rank_before_promotion = b.rank
 INNER JOIN table2 c
    ON a.rank_after_promotion = c.rank;
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com//#!2/192c84/4/0)